# Different versions of glibc RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, glibc

Before I jump into the issue, I am using RedHat 6.5 and have no access to the internet to download yum updates due to environment restrictions. All I have in this case is the CD ROM (RHEL 6.5) to utilize. After the image is updated, we utilize an internet server to pull updates but prior the server needs to be able to stand on its own.

On the image I need to utilize ldapsearch, so I did a yum whatprovides */ldapsearch to figure out which package to install.

I received:

```
openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 : LDAP client utilities
Repo        : cdrom
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/ldapsearch
```

When I go to install this package:

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# yum install openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openldap-clients.x86_64 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openldap = 2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 for package: openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openldap.i686 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.7.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsmime3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2 for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2 for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplds4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplc4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnssutil3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.3) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.8) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.6) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.3) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.9) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.5) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.1) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.11.1) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.11) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.10) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnspr4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.i686 0:2.1.23-13.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so for package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package nspr.i686 0:4.10.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss.i686 0:3.15.1-15.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nss-softokn(x86-32) >= 3.14.3 for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsoftokn3.so for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
---> Package nss-util.i686 0:3.15.1-3.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package db4.i686 0:4.7.25-18.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package nss-softokn.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsqlite3.so.0 for package: nss-softokn-3.14.3-9.el6.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package sqlite.i686 0:3.6.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6 for package: sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package readline.i686 0:6.0-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5 for package: readline-6.0-4.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package ncurses-libs.i686 0:5.7-3.20090208.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686 (cdrom)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (cdrom)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It would seem that I do not have the right package for my version installed already:

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
```

Obviously if I try and remove glibc and reinstall from the CD-ROM which would provide a newer version I receive a whole lot of errors since glibc cannot exactly be removed...

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# yum install glibc*
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Package matching glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Package matching glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-11.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686 (cdrom)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (cdrom)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What can I do to remove this _5.2 version of glibc and replace it with the newer version available on the disc?

Comment: It looks like there are some architecture problem, as the openldap-clients.x86_64 (note: 64 bit) correctly require the "openldap" package that is resolved to "openldap.i686" (note: 32 bit). This, in the end, last to the request to install the 32 bit release of the glibc (glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686) while you've installed the 64 bit (glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64). Please, tell us some details about your architecture and if you're (deliberately/not) using 32bit packages in a 64bit system.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli my attempt is to use a 64bit architecture (x86_64).  I am not deliberately using or not using 32bit packages.  I typically just install packages and the system ends up installing what it is I need.  For instance if I want to install sssd I did `yum install sssd*` so that I would obtain all the packages.

Comment: If you try to install the openldap package, what version yum will choose? 32 or 64bit? In the first case, what happens if you explicitely ask for the 64bit version (yum install openldap.x86_64)? The idea is to manually solve dependencies forcing proper architecture.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli If I try and install the openldap, allowing yum to decide the architecture I receive the message that openldap is already installed which is expected but since I also want openldap-clients

`Package openldap-clients.x86_64 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.` tries to install the 64bit package.    As in the description above, it wants to install both 32bit and 64bit packages...which then at the end glibc is all kinds of screwed up.

Comment: So, currently, the 32bit version of the "openldap" package is installare in your system? You can check with the output of "rpm -qi openldap"

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli  this is the version installed: `[root@test1 ~]# rpm -qi openldap
Name        : openldap                     Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.4.23                            Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
Release     : 34.el6_5.1                    Build Date: Tue 28 Jan 2014 06:33:23 AM PST
Install Date: Fri 08 Aug 2014 10:55:32 AM PDT      Build Host: x86-022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: openldap-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.src.rpm
Size        : 792868                           License: OpenLDAP
`

Comment: Sorry. The architecture is not explicitely shown with "-qi". I suspect it's the x86_64 package (based on the reported "Size"). Please, can you check again with "rpm -q openldap"? (without the "i" flag)

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli looks like its the 64bit package openldap-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.x86_64

Comment: Ok. So, to recap: you have the package `openldap-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.x86_64` installed on your system, but, if you try to install the openldap-clients via yum, than the dependency resolution process worked out by yum ends in several "32 bit" packages to be installed, starting from "openldap.i686 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1" and ending with "glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686". Is it correct?

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli  That is correct, I have openldap installed on my system and trying to install throws the dependency issues.  The openldap attempt to install is in the original question if you want to look through it again for the errors.  I was not the original builder of this image just inherited it.  I built a new fresh copy myself and looked at glibc and there difference was on the image with the issues I have installed `glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64` and the image where I have no issues I have `glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64`  Is that `_5.2` have something to do with it?

Comment: Ok. So let's check what happens bypassing YUM and getting straight with RPM. I suggest to download `openldap-clients.x86_64` (check at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154 , should you wonder how to do it with YUM) and then trying a manual install (only a test, not a real install) with `rpm -ivh --test openldap-clients*********.rpm`. Let us know what happens.